# Airflow DAG Scheduled To Run Once Per Minute Sometimes Doesn't Run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Some of our DAGs are scheduled to run once per minute for the first 5 minutes of a given hour.  For example, the DAG might run at:

```
20:01
20:02
20:03
20:04
20:05
```

Most of the time this works fine, but some of the time an entire DAG run is missing.  For example, the DAG might run at:

```
20:01
20:03
20:04
20:05
```

We have verbose logging turned on, but I don't see anything in the Scheduler logs at 20:02 that obviously explains why the DAG never ran.  I also don't see prolonged DAG parsing time that other issues point to as the potential culprit:

```
Number of DAGs: 177
Total task number: 259
DagBag parsing time: 7.171621999999997
```

The database resource utilization is minimal, which also is sometimes pointed to as a culprit.
If anyone has ideas of how to approach this problem or hypotheses as to what might cause a DAG not to run at a given 1 minute interval, but run fine at the next 1 minute interval please let me know.  Or if you have advice as to what you'd expect to see in the Scheduler logs when it never schedules a DAG, that would he helpful.

Comment: Please share your dag code...what is your schedule_interval ?